# Maven with OSGI dependencies

Tags: maven, osgi

I'm using maven copy-dependencies to copy my OSGI bundle dependencies to some location. Somewhere in my dependency graph I have two versions of the same artifact and maven's resolution ignores one. Anyway I can avoid this and force maven to resolve multiple versions of the same artifact?

Answer (score 0):

One of mavens core feature is [Dependency mediation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). If you have two versions of the same artifact on you graph maven will try to find the nearest version (it does not "ignore one" but decides to use the other one):

Quote:

> "Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies."

In opposite of OSGi where you can have the same bundle in different versions maven will always resolve the dependencies in a way that an artifact only exists in one (the nearest) version. If this is not possible (e.g. because to different versions are forced) you will get a conflict and the build will fail.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to disable this. Or am I better off looking at other tools? It's very handy though to have maven copy the dependencies as it can manage transitive dependencies and all.

Comment: You can not disable this behaviour if you want to benefit from the transitive dependency resolution capabilities of maven - that is just the way it works. Maybe you need to analyze the dependency tree with other goals of the dependeny plugin and handle the "duplicates with other versions" separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Embed-Dependency tags in maven-bundle-plugin, however that may not be the best approach.

> I've created this blog which explains in great detail how to cope with this OSGi issue in several ways, you might want to chose the one which fits you best: http://www.citizenrandom.com/?cat=2